# How do you static_cast an std::unordered_set?

Tags: c++, casting, stl, unordered-set

I'm trying to static_cast a unordered_set and I want to know if this is possible without undefined behavior.

Here is what I am trying to accomplish:

```
#include <unordered_set>

struct  Base{};
struct Derived : public Base{ Derived() = default; };

int main(void){
    std::unordered_set<Base *> set;
    set.insert(new Derived{});
    auto set_ptr{static_cast<std::unordered_set<Derived *>*>(&set)};
}
```

I'm trying to static_cast a set of `Base *` into a set of `Derived *`.

However this will not compile with an error:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:21:66: error: invalid static_cast from type ‘std::unordered_set*’ to type ‘std::unordered_set*’
     auto set_ptr{static_cast<std::unordered_set<Derived *>*>(&set)};
```

I was wondering if there is a way to do this without entering undefined behavior territory.

Comment: This is impossible. Why do you want to do that? Do you want to create a new set (as in the answer by @NutCracker) rather than just cast the pointer to the set as your code suggests?

Comment: @walnut I'm trying to implement a graph that has vertices that only allow certain edges between certain types of vertices. Well I could do it all dynamically but I'm challenging myself to type the vertex and edges statically. Maybe I should change the design if this is impossible.

Comment: It is hard to tell from a comment, but yes, it seems to me that you really want to change the design. Maybe you are looking for something like `std::variant`, or just compile-time polymorphism via templates.

Comment: @walnut Yes. I was trying to do compile-time polymorphism. But I guess my template black magic is just not enough yet. I will keep trying until I get it right.

Comment: "I want to do a cast" and "I want compile-time polymorphism" are two sentences that should not be put in the same story without an extremely good justification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases you cannot perform casts with respect to the template argument, such as

```
MyTemplateClass<T> foo;
MyTemplateClass<U>& bar = std::static_cast<MyTemplateClass<U>&>(foo);
```

because types `MyTemplateClass<U>` and `MyTemplateClass<T>` are completely unrelated in terms of inheritance structure. One of the two could even be specialized to be a completely different thing!

In your case `MyTemplateClass` is `std::unordered_set`.

In case of a container of pointers, such as `std::set<T*>` we have a bit more knowledge of what is contained: pointers, and there are few things that could be made:

- Ugly. Nonstandard. Dangerous. By standard it's undefined behavior.

  Just do a `reinterpret_cast<std::unorederd_set<Derived*>&>`. It will work in most cases. But it is now entirely your responsibility not to break things. For example, you must make sure that there is no `Base*` element in the set when the `std::unorederd_set<Derived*>` reference is being used. It will be very easy to forget when you pass it to a function or store as a field of some object.
- Clean but boilerplaty.

  Write an adapter. Your own implementation of `std::unordered_set<Derived*>` which holds a reference to `std::unordered_set<Base*>` underneath and performs all the necessary casts on the way, each time you access an element.

  For example, you will most likely need to write your own iterators over it. The accessor `operator*` will perform the `static_cast` or `dynamic_cast` to access its element. Or better yet, have the iterator stop only on elements that are in fact `Derived*` and skipping over all other `Base*`.

Answer (score 1):

First, instead of `static_cast`, you should use [`dynamic_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast) which:

> Safely converts pointers and references to classes up, down, and
>   sideways along the inheritance hierarchy.

Furthermore, you cannot cast whole `std::unordered_set` but you need to `dynamic_cast` each element of your `std::unordered_set` like:

```cpp
std::unordered_set<Derived *> second;
for (auto& it : first) {
    auto derived_ptr = dynamic_cast<Derived *>(&*it);
    if (nullptr != derived_ptr) {
        second.insert(derived_ptr);
    }
}
```

Please note that you need to check whether the `derived_ptr` is `nullptr` or not because, if the `dynamic_cast` **fails**, it returns the `nullptr`.

Comment: I was hoping to accomplish this without resorting to allocating another set. If there is no way maybe I should change my design.

Comment: @funnypigrun yes, you cannot cast whole collection. This is the only way to do what you want. If you liked the answer, please upvote and accept.

Comment: Yes. I like your answer but I will wait a little bit more for other answers if there are any. I'll make sure to choose one eventually.